# How to Change Position of element in responsive shopify design

Tags: css, shopify, responsive

Kinda a newb at this but I love it.... I just have a simple question in regards to editing a stylesheet in Shopify. I recorded a quick 2 minute video to show you exactly what I am trying to do. basically make a text element responsive. Also the site is royalmetalarts.com
See the video below...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBaS_HkXr_8&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution even though I don't know what it does. You have to add `body` directly after `@media (max-width: 1024px)`.(Was `@media (max-width: 1024px) .breadcrumb` now is `@media (max-width: 1024px) body .breadcrumb`)

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried it in the responsive.css stylesheet and it did work, the only problem is that it made the header image go back to its original desktop proportions in the mobile design. Maybe I am doing it in the wrong spot?

Comment: @NathanReimche-Vu Did you add `body` at the beginning of line 366?

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I was putting the body right before .breadcrumb on line 366. Now I need to know why that worked lol Thank you again!